# Calculate attribute height of point data

Tags: qgis, shapefile, fields-attributes, xyz

I have an x (easting),  y (northing) and z (height) values associated with my point shapefile.  I would like to calculate the z values from the DTM I have - how do I do this in QGIS? I am fairly new to QGIS. I can't do it in ArcGIS as don't have the extensions.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the Point sampling tool, see links below.

http://pvanb.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/sampling-raster-values-at-point-locations-in-qgis/

http://www.digital-geography.com/qgis-plugins-point-sampling-tool/