# How to include altitude using QGIS for field surveys capturing lat/long for utility locations?

Tags: qgis, xyz, altitude

I am using QGIS with a USB GPS to capture lat/long of utility locations. 
I have created a .csv file with a few fields e.g. address, cross st, id number, etc. and made it "editable".
When I locate a utility item I utilize the the live GPS "add point" feature.
QGIS adds the Lat/long (X/Y) to the first two columns of the file and "prompts" for the information from my .csv file.
I can then save the file as a .csv and I have the attributes with lat/long.

Is there an "easy" way to have QGIS add/include the altitude "Z" along with the lat/long? Would this require a special script, etc.?

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Calculate attribute height of point data](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71070/calculate-attribute-height-of-point-data).

Comment: I think the op wants to get elevation from the GPS dongle, not a DTM.

Comment: I am using a GPS dongle and elevation is correct. I can easily capture lat/long using the "add point" feature and would like to have the "add point" feature include the elevation as well.